# SQL Server T-SQL CASE error

Tags: t-sql, sql-server-2000

I am getting an error on CASE with T-SQL (SQL Server 2000). Any feedback is really appreciated

> The error is Msg 156, Level 15, State 1, Line 2  Incorrect syntax near
>   the keyword 'CASE'.

--The Query is below:

```
select c.name,c.customerid,c.linkid
      ,case when c.linkid=x.linkid then x.orderitem end as orderitem
      ,case when c.linkid=x.linkid then x.orderdate end as orderdate
from customer as c
Inner join 
(
    Select C.CustomerID, C.LinkID, O.OrderItem,O.OrderDate
    From Customer as C
    JOIN Orders as O 
        ON C.CustomerKey=O.OrderKey
    WHERE O.OrderDate='mm-dd-yyyy'
) as X
    on c.customerid=x.customerid
order by c.customerid
        ,case when c.linkid=x.linkid then 0 else 1 end asc
        ,c.linkid
```

Comment: This works fine for me, run a script as create on Customer and Order and paste here, along with maybe some sample data?

Comment: I don't get a syntax error. Are you sure you copied the code exactly? I would look for a missing comma or multiple commas between the fields.

Comment: You are forgetting the else clause of the case statement                           ,case when c.linkid=x.linkid then x.orderitem **else null** end as orderitem                                  ,case when c.linkid=x.linkid then x.orderdate **else null** end as orderdate

Comment: @AlexBlokh Else's are not required in tsql at the very least.

Comment: I tried the query in SQL 2008 and it seems valid: (http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/b7778/2) I don't think there are syntax changes for the `CASE` statement between SQL 2000 and 2008

Comment: Sorry I didn't see the responses until now. Still can't figure out why I was getting the error - when I tried it on a different system it looks like it is ok.  Thanks for the feedback.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe it has an invisible charecter between your code that you cant see,
Rewrite youe scrpit handy whithout chosing copy or past.